# Unity GameAnalytics plugin failing on iOS build

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, gameanalytics

I'm building an iOS app in unity 5.4.0f3 (the latest), with GameAnalytics plugin 3.5.2 (the latest), downloaded from https://github.com/GameAnalytics/GA-SDK-UNITY. Even with an empty project -- nothing but the plugin -- I get an error when attempting to build. The error is:

Assets/GameAnalytics/Plugins/Scripts/Wrapper/GA_Wrapper.cs(312,25): error CS0103: The name `setManualSessionHandling' does not exist in the current context

This does not happen for android or standalone desktop builds.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Where did you download the GameAnalytics plugin from? Just provide the link in your question.

Comment: Thanks, link added.

Comment: Does that error appear when you switch to a different platform other than iOS?

Comment: Added to question. Thanks. No problem for android or standalone desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the GameAnalytics code. I suggest you contact the publisher and file for bug report to get it fixed. The current workaround is to simply comment out line `312` in the `GA_Wrapper` script which is located at `Assets\GameAnalytics\Plugins\Scripts\Wrapper`.

Here is the exact code to comment out.

```
public static void SetEnabledManualSessionHandling(bool enabled)
{
    //setManualSessionHandling(enabled); //Comment out this code.
}
```

Your code should now compile. I wouldn't mess with anything else to make sure that the plugin works as expected. It is safe to comment out that line of code because what the `setManualSessionHandling;` function is only used to display `Debug.Log`.

`setManualSessionHandling` function is actually present in the script but a bad Preprocessor Directives code made it unavailable during compile time for iOS. This is a temporary fix. Again, file for a bug report to let them there is a problem with their plugin when building for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been fixed in 3.5.3. Download the latest SDK from the [GameAnalytics Unity Github repository](https://github.com/GameAnalytics/GA-SDK-UNITY).